# PROBLEM : Unicode data corrupted from ascii program

Tags: unicode, ascii

I was using html2text program to extract unicode devanagari from html file. But it is giving output as,

> "à¤¶à¥à¤°à¤¦à¥à¤§à¤§à¤¾à¤¨à¤¾à¤¨à¤¾à¤".

In Windows I would rectify this by using convert to unicode feature in Notepad++.

What to do for Ubuntu?

Update:
for testing purpose I am adding this:

> echo  आचार्यपूज्यपादानामिष्टं | html2text

renders à¤à¤à¤¾à¤°à¥à¤¯à¤ªà¥à¤à¥à¤¯à¤ªà¤¾à¤¦à¤¾à¤¨à¤¾à¤®à¤¿à¤·à¥à¤à¤

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `iconv` to convert the input to the right encoding. Unfortunatelly I cannot give you more precise help, just an example of eventual usage:

```
html2text myfile.html  |  iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 -c > good_output.txt
```

Ofcourse you have to replace your own  charsets.

Update:

In your case the working solution is to add `-utf8` parameter to `html2text`:

```
 echo आचार्यपूज्यपादानामिष्टं | html2text -utf8
```

Comment: This isnt working. Because the encoding is still utf-8. When I run `file` command it says  >xx.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with LF, NEL line terminators

Comment: See revised answer.